# How to configure High Availability in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, high-availability

I have installed SonarQube 6.3 version. Kindly guide me to enable High Availability for the sonar Server.

Comment: Read the documentation first. You need to upgrade SonarQube and buy a license.

Answer (score 0):

Elaboration on Jeroen's comment:

Consulting the ["plans-and-pricing" page](https://www.sonarsource.com/plans-and-pricing/data-center/) reveals that you can make use of the Data Center version, which comes with significant licensing costs (compared to other plans, I don't doubt the value).

The [installation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-cluster/) defines:

- the supported database versions (MySQL is currently not supported for example)
- the topology (2 application nodes, 3 search nodes)
- the need for a loadbalancer
- and of course the actual process